# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Broadcast

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I would like to develop a simple chat, but for that I need to inform all clients that a user wrote a message. Simple with one server instance, but how it works with 2+...

Is there a way to inform all registered instances in my beanstalk or how can I resolve this problem.

Thanks for help!

Regards,

Rookee

Answer (score 1):

Given your setup, the best solution is to use Amazon's SNS. This is equivalent to a JMS Topic, so, your app can subscribe to events published by other parties (probably the same app running in another instance) on the topic. Then, each consumer of the topic would broadcast the chat message to the users connected to said server.

http://aws.amazon.com/sns/